# Notation for blind people?

Tags: notation

Let's assume a person can no longer see, but he can play a musical instrument. He wants to read notes and learn new pieces. Is there any kind of notation system for such blind people?

Comment: There is definitely a braille system for music. The Spanish composer Joaquín Rodrigo was blind and composed the famous *Concierto de Aranjuez* in braille.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a braille system for music that uses the same 2X3 configuration of dots as literary braille, but ascribes different meaning to the patterns. [The Wikipedia page about musical braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_music) lists the most common symbols.

[The National Federation of the Blind](https://nfb.org/braille-music) maintains a page dedicated to braille music resources.

[Here is a link to a non-profit project](http://braillesheetmusic.com/) to provide braille sheet music for visually impaired musicians. Braille sheet music can be downloaded for free here, or printed copies can be requested for those who don't have access to a braille printer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Blind musicians can use Braille to learn new pieces, but there is only a limited amount of music available in this form.  Learning by ear is an important method too of course.